# Querying same column names from two tables of same name in different schema

Tags: postgresql

I am having two schemas say 'network' and 'sub_internals'.Both the schema contains a table called 'Connection_Point' with same column names such as 'Ao_id', Conn_objID,Loc_type,netw_type.

I want to get Conn_objID and Loc_type columns from both tables.Rule is that if Conn_objID holds value 'dtr' then Loc_type value should be either 'Primary' or 'secondary'.Now I want to query the columns of Conn_objID that starts with the value 'dtr' and does not hold 'primary' and 'secondary' as values in Loc_type.I had done query for single table and worked fine.Was struck in querying from both the table.How to accomplish using postgreSQL.The query which I had done was

```
SELECT "Conn_objID","Loc_type" 
FROM network."Connection_Point"
WHERE ("Conn_objID" LIKE 'dtr%' AND "Loc_type"  NOT LIKE ('Primary%')) 
  AND ("Conn_objID" LIKE 'dtr%' AND "Loc_type"  NOT LIKE ('Secondary%'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to pull the data from tables in both schemas into a single result set you can use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT "Conn_objID","Loc_type" 
  FROM network."Connection_Point"
  WHERE ("Conn_objID" LIKE 'dtr%' AND "Loc_type"  NOT LIKE ('Primary%')) 
    AND ("Conn_objID" LIKE 'dtr%' AND "Loc_type"  NOT LIKE ('Secondary%'))
UNION
SELECT "Conn_objID","Loc_type" 
  FROM sub_internals."Connection_Point"
  WHERE ("Conn_objID" LIKE 'dtr%' AND "Loc_type"  NOT LIKE ('Primary%')) 
    AND ("Conn_objID" LIKE 'dtr%' AND "Loc_type"  NOT LIKE ('Secondary%'));
```